# Reliable lexical binding?

Tags: lexical-scoping, let-binding, lexical-binding, closures

How does one reliably create a lexically bound/scoped variable? Consider the following:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let ((f load-file-name))
  (defun foo () f))
```

Normally `f` would be lexically bound (to the value of `load-file-name` at load time), but if anyone anywhere previously did `(defvar f VALUE)` then the code would break. (This is because `f` would become a special variable, and `let` preserves dynamic binding of special variables.)

How can I defend against such breakage?

(I don't expect anyone would ever do `(defvar f VALUE)`, but someone might use `defvar` to define a variable with a name like `argv` or `file-name` which could potentially conflict with a `let`-bound variable.)

[`lexical-let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Obsolete-Lexical-Binding.html#index-lexical_002dlet) seems to do what I want, but it is considered obsolete and it requires the use of the `cl` library. Is there no modern replacement?

Comment: As written, your explanation is not accurate as `(defvar f)` is different to `(defvar f VALUE)`.  The latter defines a special variable in the manner you've described.  The former merely marks `f` as special for the purposes of the file in which that `(defvar f)` appears, such that uses of `f` in that same file will not treat it as lexical -- but it does not *define* that variable.

Comment: Outside of some historical core cases, special variables *should* always be hyphenated and therefore (by convention only) unhyphenated lexical variable names should not be subject to the problem you've described.

Comment: @phils Example for an exception of the "hypenation-rule": `*this*` in [`ob-core.el`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/cdbb1c9633fee07f15effe6704a7fb3d8a97825e/lisp/ob-core.el#L698).

Comment: Ah, the "ear muffs" asterisks are a Common Lisp convention for naming special variables, so it would be a very sensible idea to not name any lexical variables that way either.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks @phils, I updated my question to pass a value to `defvar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an *uninterned* symbol that cannot be reached outside of the `let`.
You need that uninterned symbol two times, one time for the `let` and one time within `foo`.
The purpose of the additional outer `let`-wrapper is to provide that uninterned symbol via `make-symbol`.

```el
(let ((f-uninterned (make-symbol "f")))
  (eval
   `(let ((,f-uninterned load-file-name))
      (defun foo () ,f-uninterned))
   'lexical))
```

For the locally used symbol `f-uninterned` it is irrelevant whether lexical or dynamical binding is in effect.

So, with this snippet of Elisp, it is even irrelevant whether the buffer is loaded with lexical or dynamical binding. The `eval` with non-nil second argument ensures lexical binding for the contained backquoted form.

You get the same effect with the following elisp code. It works because a function argument (in our case the `f` of the `lambda`) is an unbound symbol:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(funcall (lambda (&optional f)
       (setq f load-file-name)
       (defun foo () f)))
```

…or similar:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(funcall (lambda (f)
       (defun foo () f))
     load-file-name)
```

Note, that using uninterned symbols is a well-known technique for macro programming, where it is even more critical, since there you are fighting local variables within user-defined functions (see the explanation [about Macros in the Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Surprising-Local-Vars.html)).

---

If you are writing your own library, say `mylib`, an alternative would be to prefix the name of the lexically bound symbol with the library name such as in `mylib-f`.

When you are writing such a library you **did** already make sure that the library name is unique. Otherwise you would have problems on a higher level than that of your question.

Assuming the library name is unique, you have control over what the symbol `mylib-f` is used for.

---

When I wrote the second `funcall` solution I thought that this would allow an easy macro definition. Furthermore, your comment on `dlet` inspired me to search for an lexical equivalent `llet`. Voila see the [comment in `cconv.el`](https://emba.gnu.org/emacs/emacs/-/blob/8fa0d9679d25c431bfe2da3d93997f5ed222ce35/lisp/emacs-lisp/cconv.el#L110).
I think they dismissed that solution because it is only working with lexical binding.

I give here a more complete definition of `llet` and an additional suitable `llet*`:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defmacro llet (bindings &rest body)
  "Do like `let' but always use lexical binding.
This only works in libraries with lexical binding."
  (declare (indent 1)
       (debug ((&rest [&or symbolp (symbolp form)])
                   body)))
  `(funcall (lambda ,(mapcar
              (lambda (binding)
            (if (consp binding)
                (car binding)
              binding))
              bindings)
          ,@body)
        ,@(mapcar
           (lambda (binding)
         (when (consp binding)
           (cadr binding)))
           bindings)))

(defmacro llet* (bindings &rest body)
  "Do like `let*' but always use lexical binding.
This only works in libraries with lexical binding."
  (declare (indent 1)
       (debug ((&rest [&or symbolp (symbolp form)])
                   body)))
  (if bindings
      `(llet ,(list (car bindings))
     ,(macroexpand
       `(llet* ,(cdr bindings)
          ,@body)))
    `(progn ,@body)))
```

Comment: Fantastic and thorough answer, thank you! I find it surprising that [`dlet`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#index-dlet) exists but we have to jump through these hoops to do the lexical equivalent of `dlet`.

Comment: @RichardHansen I've just tried it with *GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2021-03-26*. Both `funcall`-versions run like expected. Reproduction: 1. Copy above stuff into a file `"c:/temp/test.el"`. 2. Start new instance of Emacs. 3. Run `M-: (load "/temp/test.el")` 4. Run `M-: (foo)` 5. Run `M-: (setq f 1)` 6. Run `M-: (foo)`. Both instances of `(foo)` return `c:/temp/test.el`.